How can we improve performance of Experience Cloud site?
We build Experience Cloud site following Salesforce best practices but client complains about its performance and loading time.
We tried to open the page /speedtest.jsp but this page didn't provide any clue about why Experience Cloud site is slow.
We tried to add parameter ?eptVisible=1 to Experience Cloud home page but this didn't show anything neither on a live page nor in Experience Cloud preview.
Lightning Debug is turned off.
Experience Cloud site is served from CDN domain.

I think you should be able to use the Salesforce Lightning Inspector to get more information. Its last update is 3 years ago, but that should still be sufficient to get the information you're looking for.

We used Salesforce Community Page Optimizer.
Looks like Salesforce Aura framework takes the most of time of page load
window.Aura || (window.Aura = {});
window.Aura.bootstrap || (window.Aura.bootstrap = {});
window.Aura.appBootstrap = {"error":{"exceptionEvent":true,"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:clientOutOfSync"}}};
;(function() {
    window.Aura.bootstrap.execBootstrapJs = window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : Date.now();
    window.Aura.appBootstrapStatus = "loaded";
    window.Aura.afterBootstrapReady = window.Aura.afterBootstrapReady || [];
    if (window.Aura.afterBootstrapReady.length) {
        var queue = window.Aura.afterBootstrapReady;
        window.Aura.afterBootstrapReady = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
           queue[i]();
        }
    }
}());

/s/sfsites/l/%7B"mode"%3A"PROD"%2C"cac"%3A0%2C"app"%3A"siteforce%3AcommunityApp"%2C"fwuid"%3A"WFIwUmVJdmtIRnI3MTFpX0d6c1VwQWhZX25NdHFVdGpDN3BnWlROY1ZGT3cyNTAuOC4zLTYuNC41"%2C"loaded"%3A%7B"APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fsiteforce%3AcommunityApp"%3A"-X2TSlo6x6LsfpV5hla4iA"%7D%2C"mlr"%3A1%2C"pathPrefix"%3A"%2Fkb"%2C"dns"%3A"c"%2C"ls"%3A1%2C"lrmc"%3A"-386269907"%7D/bootstrap.js?aura.attributes=%7B"authenticated"%3A"true"%2C"brandingSetId"%3A"50cd6912-ba44-448a-84e4-2e59b640a1f8"%2C"formFactor"%3A"LARGE"%2C"isHybrid"%3A"false"%2C"language"%3A"en_US"%2C"pageId"%3A"692ec111-6467-47a7-8b2c-73e02f69ecd7"%2C"publishedChangelistNum"%3A"21"%2C"schema"%3A"Published"%2C"themeLayoutType"%3A"homeTheme"%2C"uds"%3A"false"%2C"viewType"%3A"Published"%7D&jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9..AK9Tbrxz73ePLsi8Z9mIiwLi5F651xF4AZOpIg8hWEA
